# Could not connect to AD ldaps from any other non-windows computer

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ssl-certificate

I have 2 domain controllers, one is PDC and also with Root CA(not best practice) and dns. the other one is just a domain controller.

I have done all needed configuration for ldaps in the second domain controller and tested ldp working fine from both the workstation and the DC itself. however I could not connect to it from linux server.
when using openssl s_client -connect dc02.domainname:636 -showcerts. it always returned no peer certificate available.

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 289 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1610484233
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Firewall and everything are OK since connection test are all good. I do know from where I can troubleshoot this problem as I can see certs are in computer store and service keystore.

Could someone provide me some hint as from where I can continue this troubleshooting and investigation?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on the permission of the cert that you are attempting to grab from the server you may want to add an everyone group and allow it to read-only or add the Linux Server to the domain via SSSD and then give the server access in the same menu. Also, ensure the cert you are attempting to push is publicly visible.

REF (How to add a Linux machine to AD): https://www.datasunrise.com/blog/professional-info/integrating-a-linux-machine-into-windows-active-directory-domain/

[CA Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knnot.png)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that port 88 is also needed when doing ldaps authentication and etc. when open port 88 for both tcp and udp, the test and everything works fine.

Thanks for the suggestions.